# C# WebBrowser как программно удалить cookie

Tags: c#, cookie, webbrowser

у меня вопрос, мне на кнопку нужно повесить два действия, 1 - Это перейти на другую страницу сайта, 2 - Удалить куки WebBrowser (IE 11). Вот код моей кнопки:

```
private void toolStripButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://site.ru/logout.php");
        Task.Run(() => webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())"));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**webBrowser1.Navigate** - Переходит на страницу логаута (происходит выход пользователя с сайта), далее мне нужно чтоб браузер удалил куки этого сайта, использую **Tusk.Run** со скриптом найденным в интернете. Но проблема в том, что такая кнопка не работает, а точнее не происходит логаут с сайта, только сбрасываются куки, ни каких ошибок нет, код исполняется, в чем проблема и как её решить я не пойму, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: А если временно убрать таску - логаут происходит? Если да, значит в текущем виде он просто не успевает произойти до того, как запускается таска и браузер переходит к выполнению другого задания. Стало быть, нужно дожидаться завершения отработки страницы с логаутом (событие DocumentCompleted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение:** Как подсказали в комментариях, браузер не успевал переходить по первой ссылке как уже начинал переходить по второй. Решил проблему подписавшись на событие DocumentCompleted, добавлю код решения, вдруг кому пригодится.
Кнопка:

```
private void toolStripButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://site.ru/logout.php");
        Console.WriteLine("LogOut");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Метод который срабатывает после нажатия кнопки и после завершения перехода по site.ru/logout.php очищая куки.

```
public void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
    Task.Run(() => webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())"));
    Console.WriteLine("Clear Cookies");
}
```